# Response in nestjs-grpc microservice

Tags: nestjs, grpc

I am getting this kind of response in the postman from my nestjs-gRPC microservice which is not readable:

```
{
    "message": "Logged In Successfully.",
    "data": {
        "user": "{\n  _id: new ObjectId(\"64770e2de47429bedcb24a85\"),\n  email: 'a@a.com',\n  password: '$2a$10$Grnc1u7/g4r1rnZofWrj.e6EmqMQQrDnqBrs/pNgOYF9cmQ4p9k8q',\n  name: 'John Doe',\n  phone: '1234567890',\n  type: 'ADMIN',\n  createdAt: 2023-05-31T09:06:53.671Z,\n  updatedAt: 2023-05-31T09:06:53.671Z,\n  __v: 0\n}",
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0NzcwZTJkZTQ3NDI5YmVkY2IyNGE4NSIsInVzZXJUeXBlIjoiQURNSU4iLCJpYXQiOjE2ODU3NzM3NzUsImV4cCI6MTY4NTc3NDY3NX0.sl99Rg77fKRRZEnJ3eWQ2X6jR7svaJWdXsciUSh80zc"
    }
}
```

This is the user.service.proto file code:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package user;

service UserService {
  rpc Login (LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse) {}
}

message LoginRequest {
  string email = 1;
  string password = 2;
}

message LoginResponse {
  string message = 1;
  map<string, string> data = 2;
}
```

The controller method in user-microservice:

```
@GrpcMethod('UserService', 'Login')
  async login(@Payload() payload: Login): Promise<User | null> {
    const { email, password } = payload;
    const user = await this.usersService.login(email, password);

    return sendSuccess(SUCCESS.S200.LOGIN, user);
  }
```

The login service function in user microservice:

```
async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = (await this.findByEmail(email)) as User;

    const comparepassword = await passwordService.comparePasswords(
      password,
      user.password,
    );
    if (user && comparepassword) {
      const payload = {
        id: user._id,
        userType: user.type,
      };
      const token = jwtService.generateAccessToken(payload);
      return { user, token };
    }

    return 'User not found';
  }
```

The controller method in API gateway:

```
@Post('login')
  @HttpCode(200)
  async login(
    @Body() loginData: Login,
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const user = await firstValueFrom(this.userService.Login(loginData));

      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Login failed');
    }
  }
```

I have tried different things to remove those unnecessary characters from the response, like parsing the JSON, inspect method from utils library but still getting the same response with a changes or 2 but they are more weird than above.

Comment: `map<string, string> data` - I think you need to define your `data` message type better. Make a specific message type for `data` and nest a `user` type.

Comment: @J.Titus Tried that as well
```message User {
  string id = 1;
  string email = 2;
  string name = 3;
  string phone = 4;
}```

The loginResponse:
```message LoginResponse {
  string message = 1;
  User user = 2;
  string token = 3;
}```

Getting error that Login Failed

Comment: You regenerated the handler functions after doing that? Your `LoginResponse` message type is not equivalent to the structure you were receiving before.

Comment: @J.Titus Sorry, I didn't get your question